# Browser: Drag and drop image from explorer replaces content instead of opening in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, windows-explorer, browser, images, drag-and-drop

Drag and drop image from explorer replaces content.

This behaviour can end up cause data loss. Consider this use case: you are filling in a long form and you have a box to upload an images at the end which supports drag and drop. When you dragged an image from the file browser, you accidentally drop the image outside the box in the website.

**What should happen?**

Browser opens the image I dropped in a new tab.

**What happens?**

Browser load the image in the page you dropped. Clicking back button will reload the page, making you lose all the data you typed.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?